# Explain why graph of $f(x)=(x+1)\sin(3x)$ lies below the $x$-axis in interval $[4\pi/9,5\pi/9]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$f(x)=(x+1)\sin(3x)$

Explain why the graph of $f$ lies below the $x$-axis for values of $x$ in the interval $[4\pi/9, 5\pi/9]$.

From what I know/understand, I'd have to look at the function in two parts: $y=x+1$ and $y=\sin(3x)$ and then construct a table of signs to figure out what's happening to the whole function.

For $y=x+1$ the function is increasing on its whole domain and the $x$ intercept of its graph is $x=-1$.

For $y=\sin(3x)$ I come a little undone. I don't know how to find the $x$ intercept to be able to have a value for my table of signs. What alternative method can I use?

Comment: In no way is the function $y=x+1$ _decreasing anywhere_ in it's domain. What is the gradient of $y$?

Comment: Sorry I meant increasing

Comment: Thats ok, just make an edit to your original post. Also, to find the $x$ intercept of the function $y=\sin(3x)$, set $y=0$ as you always do. Then solve for $x$, noting that $\sin(X) = 0$ when $X$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$ (Graph $\sin(x)$ and see where it crosses the $x$ axis).

Comment: consider $g(\theta)=f(\frac{\theta}{3})=(\frac{\theta}{3}+1)\sin \theta$ where $\theta\in[4\pi/3, 5\pi/3]$

Answer (score 1):

first find the critical points($x$ at which $f(x)= 0$ or undefined). luckily your function $f$ is defined everywhere. because $f$ is already factored, finding the zeros are made easier. the critical numbers are given by $$(x+1)\sin 3x = 0 \to x = -1 \text{ or} \sin 3x = 0 \to x = -1, 3x = 0, \pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, \cdots $$ dividing by $3,$ the critical numbers of $f$ are
$$\cdots, -2\pi/3, -1, -\pi/3, 0, \pi/3, 2\pi/3, \cdots $$

now pick a test point in each these intervals and the sign of $f$ at that point should determine the sign for all points in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you know the period of $sin(x)$. When a factor greater than $1$ (or less than $-1$) is placed inside the $sin$ function and next to the $x$, it shortens the period by that factor. One way to think of it is that the factor is "accelerating" the $x$ values so the whole function completes each cycle "more quickly". So the period for $y=sin(3x)$ is $1/3$ the size of the period of $y=sin(x)$.

You can graph $y=sin(x)$, and just relabel all the $x$ values where it crosses the $x$ axis with $1/3$ their normal value. So instead of crossing at $\pi$, it would cross at $\pi /3$ (for example). That should make it easier to chart the positive and negative values of $y=sin(3x)$.

Comment: I've have managed to come up with: when x = (infinity,-1) x+1=negative, sin (3x)=negative so whole function = negative. when x=-1, x+1=0 sin(3x)=negative so function=0. for (-1,0) x+1=positive, sin(3x)=negative so function=negative. for 0 x+1=positive, sin(3x)=0 so function =0. for (0,pi/3_ x+1=positive, sin(3x)=positive so function=positive. for pi/3 x+1=positive sin(3x)=positive so whole function= positive. How does this then show that the graph lies below the x axis for the above interval?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading your comment, but I think you're on the right track. On the interval $(0,\pi /3)$, $f$ is positive, so you have that much. What happens between $\pi /3$ and the next larger zero for $y=sin(3x)$? What is the next larger zero for $y=sin(3x)$? Finally, how do $4\pi /9$ and $5\pi /9$ compare with $\pi /3$ and the next zero crossing?